# Non-parametric tests with covariate

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, predictor

I have two groups of biological samples from a population: data on parasitized fish and non-parasitized fish. I want to compare the values of some biological indexes between these groups but I need to control for size. Since my data does not fit the normal distribution, even after log transformation, I wonder if there is any way to perform a non-parametric test while using size as a covariate.
My statistical knowledge is a bit limited.

Comment: Try looking at [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41270/nonparametric-equivalent-of-ancova-for-continuous-dependent-variables)